# Could light sails (solar sails) in series accelerate each other?

Tags: solar-sails

Lets say we build 3 light sails that each also contain a forward facing laser. I'll attempt to draw that by the following symbol:  `|->`
We arrange them in space in a linear series.
So the series would resemble:

```
 |->    |->    |->
sail0  sail1  sail2
```

At time zero, we turn on the lasers of the first 2.  In the absence of sunlight, what would happen?

I think the first sail would not move (no force). The 2nd sail would be accelerated by first sail's laser. Would the 3rd sail experience the same acceleration as the 2nd? Or would it experience an increased rate of acceleration because the light it receives is blue-shifted?

Comment: Recall that the forward facing laser supply a backward thrust to its sail ...

Comment: In essence this creates a somewhat complicated photon accelerated ordinary multi-stage rocket. One might as well expel the matter of the first sail with a more conventional and far less wasteful mechanism than photons, which would only be useful if all of this setup was moving at near the speed of light.

Comment: I think that is the point I was missing. The laser does create a backwards thrust.

Comment: So, sail0 moves along the -x axis. Sail1 probably stays still or barely moves and Sail2 moves along the +x axis.?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's suppose that "turn on the lasers" means "emit a very short pulse of light." Then at time $0^+$ right afterwards we have:

Sails 0 and 1 at positions $0$ and $L$, moving backwards with velocity $-v$, and sail 2 at position $2L$ standing still, plus two bursts A and B at positions $0$ and $L$, moving forwards with velocity $+c$.

About the time $\tau \approx L/c$ afterwards (a little before) the light pulse from sail 0 will hit sail 1 and reflect, giving it velocity $+v.$  At the time $L/c$, the light pulse from sail 1 will hit sail 2 and reflect, giving it velocity $+2v$. So now you have:

- Sail 0 at position $-v\tau$ moving with speed $-v,$
- Sail 1 approximately at position $L-v\tau$ moving with speed $+v,$
- Sail 2 at position $2L$ moving with speed $+2v,$ and
- Two light pulses, the first approximately at $L - v\tau$ and the other at $2L$, moving with velocities $-c.$

At this point the problem becomes ill-defined because you haven't specified if the lasers now reflect off of their original solar sails or whether they deflect off into space. Furthermore it's not specified if the front of the solar sails is also a perfect reflector, or a perfect absorber, or what.

If the "wrong side" of the sail is a perfect absorber, for example, then the light pulses at time $2\tau$ will be absorbed, leading to extra momentum for sail 0 (now moving with velocity $-2v$) but a total cancellation for sail 1 (now moving with velocity $0$.) Furthermore the timescales are nice enough that sail 1 has, to first order, stayed at position $L$. It would be interesting to work out the details of the "approximately at" times to see if sail 1 has in fact drifted slightly to the sides or not at this time.